# Salvar uma imagem no camanjs

Tags: php, javascript

Boa tarde,

Estou usando o plugin camanjs e não estou conseguindo salvar a imagem para o servidor, tenho o código assim:

```
<img id="camanimage" src="image.jpg" style="height:200px;">
```

No javascript:

```
Caman("#camanimage", function () {  
  this.brightness(10);
  this.contrast(10);

  this.render(function(){

    //this.save(); Funciona

    var imagedata = this.toBase64();
```

solução: faltava esta linha para retirar a parte inicial do data image:

```
    var raw_image_data = imagedata.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\;base64\,/, '');


    $.post("salvafoto.php", { imagedata: raw_image_data },
      function(info){
      }
    );
// ...
```

Depois no `salvafoto.php` tenho assim:

```
$encodedData = base64_decode($_POST['imagedata']);
$result = file_put_contents( 'teste.jpg', $encodedData );
```

Ao abrir a imagem fica sempre a preto com erro. Alguém sabe porque? Se usar o `this.save()` faz o download mas funciona.

Comment: Qual o valor de `imagedata`? Talvez tenha algum caractere que a função no php não reconheça..

Comment: aparece este código(não esta completo porque não cabe: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPgAAAEgCAYAAACZy779AAAgAElEQVR4Xuy9+3Oc13nneYBGA2igceUFvEikRNEWbVmKFNvKWDveZJKtzGztz/sH7i9TW5utmpqtTG0qO/bGlRpnJzU19lijWIolxaJFUSBIXBtooC/Afj7POQdsM3JkSXQIkHhVFG7db7/99vme5/Z9vs

Comment: Então já conseguiu resolver? Escreve uma resposta e marca como solucionado para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida. Abçs.

Answer (score 1):

solução: faltava esta linha para retirar a parte inicial do data:image:

```
 var raw_image_data = imagedata.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\;base64\,/, '');
```